# How to prove transitive property of parallel lines for 3 non-coplanar lines.

Tags: geometry, proof-writing

Given: for lines a, b, c; a||b, b||c, and a,b,c non-coplanar
Prove a||c

I seem to gitten to a point where if I can prove a and c are not skewed, then they are parallel, but I just can't figure out how to prove they are not skewed. Or to put it another way, I have to prove a and c are coplanar to prove they are parallel. Or maybe I'm off even on that. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

$$
\left\{ \matrix{
  a||b\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  {\bf a} = {\bf a}_{\,0}  + \alpha \,{\bf u} \hfill \cr 
  {\bf b} = {\bf b}_{\,0}  + \beta \,{\bf u} \hfill \cr}  \right. \hfill \cr 
  b||c\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  {\bf b} = {\bf b}_{\,0}  + \beta \,{\bf u} \hfill \cr 
  {\bf c} = {\bf c}_{\,0}  + \gamma \,{\bf u} \hfill \cr}  \right. \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad \left\{ \matrix{
  {\bf a} = {\bf a}_{\,0}  + \alpha \,{\bf u} \hfill \cr 
  {\bf c} = {\bf c}_{\,0}  + \gamma \,{\bf u} \hfill \cr}  \right.\quad  \Rightarrow \quad a||c
$$

Comment: I'm guessing you are using slope in 3d but I'm not allowed to use that. Sort of like how the proof for transitivity of parallelism in 2d space is proven using a transversal instead of slope.

Comment: @HongKim: the above is according to the vectorial definition of lines, which might be assimilated to "slope".  Of course there are many other approaches: so please edit your post to precisely define what you are looking for, and in which field of geometry you are operating.

Comment: @G cab Sorry for not being clear. Its high school geometry for freshmans. The tools we are allowed to use are pretty basic. We have definitions of lines and planes based on 2 or 3 points. Theorems for proving congruent and similar triangles/working with their properties. Being able to define angle and side lengths using ruler/proctractor axiom. Properties of parallel lines minus slope such as the parallel postulate and that parallel lines remain equidistant from each other. Properties of transversals cutting parallel lines. Triangle inequality/scalene theorems. Thank you.